# How do you authenticate user generated "apps" for your app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, user-generated-content

I'm think something like Facebook apps here.  User generated pieces of code that people can write to interact with my app.

I understand how an authenticated API works, but this seems a little more complicated because not only does the APP have to authenticate itself (with a regular api-key) but the USER using the app has to be authenticated somehow too, without giving the app free reign.

I've been reading a bit here to see how FB does it: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/How_Facebook_Authenticates_Your_Application

And it looks like you have to pass a signature in addition to the api-key along with every call, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how this gets generated and used on the other end (my server).

Figure there must be a simple explanation of this out there?  Thanks!

P.S. I'm building a Rails app if there are any applicable gems/plugins.

Comment: Only some calls (things that act on behalf of a user, mostly) require a session key -- there a number of calls that work fine without. The actual method Facebook uses to hand the session key off to different applications differ on the type/setup of the application. The session key is only temporary (one hour) and is only sent to "allowed" applications. The question deserves more good (non SO?) research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what I need:

http://github.com/phurni/authlogic_api

Comment: The top answer here was also revealing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247110/looking-for-suggestions-for-building-a-secure-rest-api-within-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any success with **authlogic_api**? I'm working on the server-side for a Steam game, where users are logged in through Steam, so I'm only responding to REST calls from the client (no user login required). The rdocs for authlogic_api give some brief set-up info, but I'm struggling with what to do in the application_controller to restrict access; essentially the equivalent of this code from the **authlogic** example:

http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/5819a13477797d758cb6871f475ed1c54bf8a3a7/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

Comment: I ended up going a different route on this project, so not sure - it may have worked.  Sorry I couldn't be more help!  Making a Steam game sounds pretty fun though.

Comment: Worked well in the end. Details here for anyone who stumbles across this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111869/using-authlogic-api-for-rails-rest-api-access