# Using authlogic_api for Rails REST API access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, rest, authlogic

I am writing a Rails back-end API for a Steam game that is only accessed via REST calls, so no user-specific authentication is required. I am trying to implement the [**authlogic_api plug-in**](http://github.com/phurni/authlogic_api) for the **Authlogic** gem, which uses an api_key/signature mechanism to restrict access. I have implemented the *ApplicationSession* and *ApplicationAccount* models as outlined in the rdocs, but I'm not sure how to modify my *ApplicationController* to restrict access.

Looking at the source, it appears the authlogic_api plug-in modifies the *ActsAsAuthentic* and *Session* modules from Authlogic. But since this is essentially "single access" authentication, requiring the API key and signature to be passed on every request, I don't see how sessions would be a factor.

Has anyone successfully implemented authlogic_api in their apps? If so, would you share your approach for setting up your *ApplicationController*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's much simpler. Using all that code from the Authlogic example is somewhat overkill - it mainly manages storing session details, which you don't need to do for the Application (also known as Client) session. The Client session is re-confirmed at every request.

All you need is:

**models\client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |config|
  end
end
```

**models\client_session.rb**

```
class ClientSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  api_key_param 'app_key'
end
```

**controllers\application_controller**

```
before_filter :verify_client

def verify_client
  @client_session = ClientSession.new()
  unless @client_session.save # if client session not successfully created using the api_key and signature, render an error and block the request
    @error = {:description => "Couldn't validate client application."}
    render :template => 'errors/error.xml.builder'
  end
end
```

You also need to run a migration to create the clients table. Not all of the fields below are necessary, but they won't hurt.

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :clients do |t|
      # human fields
      t.string :name
      t.string :owner
      t.string :owner_email
      t.string :owner_phone
      # login fields
      t.string :api_key, :null => false
      t.string :api_secret, :null => false
      t.string :password_salt
      t.string :persistence_token
      t.string :perishable_token
      # automagical fields (courtesy of authlogic & authlogic_api)
      t.integer :failed_login_count
      t.datetime :last_request_at
      t.integer :request_count
      t.string :last_request_ip
      # automagical fields (courtesy of rails)
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :clients
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need the overhead of Authlogic.

If you are generating a URL that the client will then send, just add an expiration timestamp, and do an MD5 hash (signature) on the entire URL, adding the result as a final query paramter.

Please a before_filter on the controller action, i.e. a signed_url method that will validate the URL. This method should get the URL from the request object. Verify the expiration has not passed. Remove the signature from the URL to place it in the same form as was used to generate the original URL, do so, and verify a match. Voila.

Expiration is important to be sure that URL's cannot be re-used later.

This is a great method to centralize as an alternate way to authorize requests without requiring a login. As long as you have generated the URL, it will be valid until expiration from any host.

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, I don't understand how this would authenticate that the incoming request is from a valid client? The api key/signature mechanism at least requires the client to provide those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by following the [Authlogic example](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/master/README.rdoc), and just substituting a ClientAccount model for the User model. So in my Application controller I have:

```
before_filter :require_client

def require_client
  unless current_client
    store_location
    render :text => 'Authentication failed', :status => 401
    return false
  end
end

def require_no_client
  if current_client
    store_location
    render :text => 'Client session already exists', :status => 401
    return false
  end
end

def current_client_session
  return @current_client_session if defined?(@current_client_session)
  @current_client_session = ClientSession.find
end

def current_client
  return @current_client if defined?(@current_client)
  @current_client = current_client_session && current_client_session.record
end
```

The ClientAccount model acts_as_authentic, and the ClientSession model handles creating and destroying the sessions for Authlogic (authenticate_with ClientAccount):

```
class ClientSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_client, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_client, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @client_session = ClientSession.new
  end

  def create
    @client_session = ClientSession.new(params[:client_session])
    if @client_session.save
      redirect_back_or_default account_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_client_session.destroy
    redirect_back_or_default new_client_session_url
  end
end
```

This solution has worked well, as we're able to generate different API key/signature combos for different clients, which gives us additional usage data. The only "gotcha" is if you're doing something like a multipart file upload, since the POST hash uses the raw POST data.