# Ruby on Rails API Security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, api, oauth

For a recent project a friend of mine and I have been working on, we want to build a RESTful web API for client application usage. I believe that I have a fairly good grasp of the top-down picture after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247110/looking-for-suggestions-for-building-a-secure-rest-api-within-ruby-on-rails), but am fairly clueless when it comes to security issues.

I know of OAuth and plan on implementing it, but are there any other concerns we should address first thing? I would hate to spend a large amount of time developing these features to find out later that we've left the site open for malicious attack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for general information on Web security, check out [OWASP Ruby on Rails Security Guide V.2](https://www.owasp.org/images/8/89/Rails_Security_2.pdf).  (There's also a [first edition](http://www.lulu.com/items/volume_64/5811000/5811294/3/print/5811294.pdf) which I read back in the day.)  Check out OWASP's web site for more security related information.

Comment: Very good resource. I waited to read it all before I accepted, but this answers pretty much all concerns I had.

Answer (score 1):

A few more resources for you:

Great walkthrough of common web attacks and how to deal with them in rails
https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/guides/2013/03/09/ruby-security-tutorial-and-rails-security-guide

Rails insecure defaults
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/03/27/rails-insecure-defaults

All about sql injection, goes beyond the simple examples
http://rails-sqli.org

[New security issues are listed at](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=Ruby&search_type=all&cves=on)