# Android login with RAILS info

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, web-services, authentication

I want to know how can I authenticate a user on an android app using a RAILS web service... and how to store his/her credentials for further use

Comment: Of course you can do this. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm just starting now... but i'm working on android alone and my friend is in charge of rails,  can you tell me a way to do this o refer me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is that you can use build rest API's using rails that would authenticate a given set of credentials. Then you can call this API using standard HTTP requests and store the tokens in many different secure ways.

Here's a good project I found which implements another method  to authenticate users of an android app using rails:

http://www.strukturedkaos.com/2011/09/19/soup-to-nuts-token-authentication-for-android-using-rails-3-devise/

Here's another great thread on this site discussing another solution:

[What can I use to allow an android app to communicate with a rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294229/what-can-i-use-to-allow-an-android-app-to-communicate-with-a-rails-app)